# What should we do about questions where the answer is in a comment?

Tags: discussion

Example: [How can I use msg.value twice?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1318/42)

Do we ping the answerer to also write an answer on it?  We don't want to take credit away from the initial person who answered.

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments

Comment: Ok, your comment almost fits that...  You can post it and I'll accept :)

Comment: I did, but it was a "trivial answer" and converted to a comment. I've filled it out a bit now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the accepted answer here: [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments). In brief, give them a chance to do that (using @username) and if they don't after a while, do it yourself.